# Can't access the NODE_ENV environment variable properly, is this a bug with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm accessing the NODE_ENV environment variable to turn on some debug features in a node.js server. It used to work like a charm, but now I'm facing some very weird stuff. Here's what I'm doing:

```
// check if the env var is OK
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);

// WTF???
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "development") {
    console.log("ok");
}
else {
    console.log("nope");
}

// sanity check
var str = "development";
if (str == "development") {
    console.log("ok");
}
else {
    console.log("nope");
}
```

And here is what I get:

```
development
nope
ok
```

How is that possible? Am I facing a bug in node.js? If not, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Following Pointy's comment below, here's what I get if I change my initial log to `console.log("[" + process.env.NODE_ENV + "]");`:

```
]development
nope
ok
```

So, a known issue maybe?

Comment: Change it to `console.log("[" + process.env.NODE_ENV + "]");` to see if there are trailing spaces maybe

Comment: @Pointy Done, see my edit. So. Enlighten me :)

Comment: Ah - well it looks to me as if your environment variable does indeed have some funny characters in it - maybe a carriage return at the end?

Comment: When I run your script as posted originally, with the Linux command line `NODE_ENV=development node /tmp/p.js` it works correctly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like your environment variable has some funny characters, possibly due to the way it's being set outside of Node.js.  You could try this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV.replace(/\W/g, '') == 'development') {
  console.log('ok');
}
```

Comment: Yep, you're right! I was setting the variable with a script with Windows line endings, if I set it directly in bash the issue vanishes! Well, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Windows machine then restart your machine after setting an environment variable to take effect.

after restarting retrieve the value in node.js using app.get('NODE_ENV') or `process.env.NODE_ENV`